# Image file getting removed after reading in rails seeds file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shrine

Using this in rails seeds file for picking random images.

```
Room.all.each do |room|
  count = rand(1..5)
  count.times do
    room.photos.create!(
        image: File.new(Dir['app/assets/images/sampleimages/*.jpg'].sample))
  end
end
```

But after reading its removing that image from my assets folder. What could be the issue here? Is the above code suppose to do that or is it something to do with `shrine`(image uploader)?

Using version `Rails 5.2.0` and `shrine 2.10.1`.

My full `imageUploader.rb`

```
class ImageUploader < Shrine
  include ImageProcessing::MiniMagick
  plugin :processing
  plugin :determine_mime_type
  plugin :remove_attachment
  plugin :store_dimensions
  plugin :validation_helpers
  plugin :versions
  plugin :pretty_location
  plugin :delete_raw

  Attacher.validate do
    validate_max_size 5.megabytes, message: 'is too large (max is 5 MB)'
    validate_mime_type_inclusion ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']
  end

  def process(io, context)
    case context[:phase]
    when :store
      original = io.download
      pipeline = ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.source(original)
      size_300 = pipeline.resize_to_fit!(300, 300)
      size_150 = pipeline.resize_to_fill!(150, 150)
      original.close!
      {original: io, medium: size_300, thumb: size_150}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If you are saying you are using `Shrine`, can you post the list of its plugins you are using as well

Comment: @seethrough updated

Comment: You're probably loading the `delete_raw` plugin in your uploader, which is intended for deleting processed image thumbnails after uploading, but will delete any raw files as an unfortunate side effect. This functionality should really be part of the `versions` plugin, I'll push a change to master to make that change.

Comment: You can work around this by telling the `delete_raw` plugin to delete only the raw files uploaded to permanent storage: `plugin :delete_raw, storages: [:store]`.

Comment: @janko-m Thank you for the heads up. I was wondering what I did wrong for this behaviour. I now remember adding the delete_raw a while ago. But recently I used my `seeds.rb` and noticed the issue. If you can provide as an aswer I can give you proper credit and thank you for this awesome gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw file objects will get automatically deleted after upload if `delete_raw` plugin is loaded. It's recommended to load this plugin when using `versions`, as you want processed image thumbnails to get deleted locally after they're uploaded. However, it has an unfortunate side effect that by default it will also delete input files.

Assigned files will get uploaded to temporary storage, so you can work around this by telling the `delete_raw` plugin to only delete raw files that are uploaded to permanent storage:

```
plugin :delete_raw, storages: [:store]
```